# init of custom property go UIView using function swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have UiView with **ColorOfGradient** property in init.

```
class WarningView: UIView {
    var colorOfGradient: String?
    
    
    convenience init(colorOfGradient: String?) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        self.colorOfGradient = colorOfGradient
    }

override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print(colorOfGradient as Any) // prints nil
    }
}
//...
```

There is function which contains **color** in args. Then **color** used in init

```
public func setOnVc(whereToAdd: UIViewController, text: String, color: String?, heightMultiplier: CGFloat){
    let whatToAdd = WarningView(colorOfGradient: color)
//...
}
```

And here is the usage of those function

```
public func showWarningOfFutureDate1(_ vc: UIViewController){
    setOnVc(whereToAdd: vc, text: "⛔️lalala⛔️", color: "red", heightMultiplier: 0.06)
}
```

But print(colorOfGradient as Any) at UIView prints nil. How to transfer string? "red" to **colorOfGradient** at UIVIew

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have created color assets, you cannot use a string name for a color.

Change your property to a `UIColor`:

```
class WarningView: UIView {
    // give it a default value
    var colorOfGradient: UIColor = .blue
    
    convenience init(colorOfGradient: UIColor?) {
        self.init(frame: CGRect.zero)
        
        // unwrap optional
        if let c = colorOfGradient {
            self.colorOfGradient = c
        }
        // print the newly set color
        print("Color is now:", self.colorOfGradient as Any)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("Color at init:", colorOfGradient as Any)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

You can then do this:

```
public func setOnVc(whereToAdd: UIViewController, text: String, color: UIColor?, heightMultiplier: CGFloat){
    
    let whatToAdd = WarningView(colorOfGradient: color)
    //...
}

public func showWarningOfFutureDate1(_ vc: UIViewController){
    setOnVc(whereToAdd: vc, text: "⛔️lalala⛔️", color: .red, heightMultiplier: 0.06)
}
```

and the `print(colorOfGradient as Any)` line will give you this (if you pass `.red`):

```
UIExtendedSRGBColorSpace 0 0 1 1
```

Comment: but it always prints blue color

Comment: @fonzyara - Yes, at that point, you haven't initialized the **new** color yet, so it prints the default blue. I edited the code in my answer so it now prints the color at `init` and then then newly-set color value (sorry, thought you understood that).